# Django local http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Is Not Connecting

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently trying out a Django Tutorial(link below), and after I type in
"python manage.py runserver" , and click on the link provided, I recieve this error:
[ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emoQc.pn)

I disabled all of my firewalls and antivirus programs, and am extremely confused as I know nothing about Django.

Tutorial link:https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/

I have tried other tutorials, and recieved the exact same error.

Comment: There is something wrong with picture, please fix it

Comment: Did you add `'*'` to your allowed hosts in `settings.py`?